# See the modifications in Change logs on the source contact

Tags: contacts

Title says all, in any contact summary I can see what has been done to the target contact (the one I'm looking at) by who has done it (AKA `Changed by`).

What if I want to see what the source of the change has done for other contacts?

In the `Activities` tab (on the source contact's side) I can't see the little improvements like `added group` or `update contact` did by this person on some contacts.

Is there a kind of `Change logs from the source contact side`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Turn on logging at Administer - System Settings - Misc.
2. Make some changes to records.
3. Go to Reports - Contact Reports - Contact Logging Report (Summary)
4. Then on the filters tab you can filter by "Altered By".

Note the report is not complete and is very contact-centric and not always good for other objects, so for example changes related to activities don't show up very well. But for contact changes it works.

Comment: thanks!!! This is almost what we were looking for